# Substring de un txto SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de quedarme sólo con la parte que dice yes de la cadena:

> 'C:\Direction\Other\No\No\Yes\Yes\Yes\Yes'

La idea es que al final me quede:

```
campo 1 | campo 2 | campo 3 | campo 4 | campo 5
  algo  |   yes   |   yes   |   yes   |   yes
```

Lo que dice no lo descartaría y lo que dice sí iría en campos diferentes.

Ahora bien, ¿Son diferentes substrings? ¿O tengo que usar una expresión regular?

Mi consulta es sobre SQL Server

Comment: ¿Que versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17277.0

Comment: Decía la del motor, prueba con `select @@Version`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3460.0 (X64)   Jul 22 2014 15:22:00   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: El tema es bastante complejo aunque no lo parezca, en primer lugar hay que hacer un `split` de la cadena. En la versión de SQL no tienes todavía una función para eso, por lo que habría que crear una, con el split crearíamos una tabla con cada uno de los valores , el nuevo problema es que deberíamos  luego transformar la salida "vertical" a una "horizontal", también se puede pero no es una solución trivial. Pero además si la cantidad de valores a separar es variable, esto agrega otro problema.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar mas contexto a tu problema? ¿Que representa esta cadena? ¿La información está en la columna de una tabla? ¿Siempre tiene la misma cantidad de valores a separar?  ¿La salida es para alimentar un informe, otra tabla, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si mal no entendí tu pregunta, se me ocurriría que primero hagas un split por el signo "\" , luego te barras este array de resultados y antes de mandarlos a guardar valides si el dato == 'Yes' lo almacenas, caso contrario lo descartas.

Sería algo así:
(
    @Texto VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimitador CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @output TABLE(Datos VARCHAR(MAX)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Empieza INT, @Termina INT
    SELECT @Empieza = 1, @Termina= CHARINDEX(@Delimitador , @Texto )
    WHILE @Empieza < LEN(@Texto ) + 1 BEGIN
        IF @Termina = 0
            SET @Termina = LEN(@Texto ) + 1

```
    INSERT INTO @output (Datos)  
    VALUES(SUBSTRING(@Texto , @Empieza , @Termina - @Empieza ))
    SET @Empieza = @Termina + 1
    SET @Termina = CHARINDEX(@Delimitador , @Texto , @Empieza )

END
RETURN
```

END

Comment: ¿hacer 'array[i] == 'Yes'' en SQL? con Management Studio?